# How do I display a JavaScript alert using my PHP variables?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to bring up a javascript alert with my variables from php. My upload.php file so far is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{
    $pic = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['pic']['name'];
    $pic_loc = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
    $folder="uploaded_files/";
    if(move_uploaded_file($pic_loc,$folder.$pic))
    {
        ?><script>alert('File successfully uploaded.\n![File Upload]('+window.location.href+')');
</script><?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?><script>alert('Sorry, error while uploading file. Please try again');</script><?php
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Photo Uploader for use in markdown</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Photo Uploader & Markdown generator</h2>
<p>Click 'Choose file' to choose the file to be uploaded. The filename should appear. Then click 'upload'. <br>A popup should show you what to copy and paste.</p>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="pic" />
<button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I then have my html code which looks like (only the relevant part included):

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="pic" />
<button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
```

The purpose of this script is to upload a picture to a server and then display the markdown code for the user to use that image. I am aiming to output the following if the file uploads correctly:
`![Alternative Text](http://www.example.com/folder/photo.jpg)`

I have tried the following:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{
    $pic = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['pic']['name'];
    $pic_loc = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
    $folder="uploaded_files/";
    if(move_uploaded_file($pic_loc,$folder.$pic))
    {
        ?><script>alert('File successfully uploaded.\n![File Upload]('+window.location.href+.$folder.'/'.$pic.')');</script><?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?><script>alert('Sorry, error while uploading file. Please try again');</script><?php
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Photo Uploader for use in markdown</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Photo Uploader & Markdown generator</h2>
<p>Click 'Choose file' to choose the file to be uploaded. The filename should appear. Then click 'upload'. <br>A popup should show you what to copy and paste.</p>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="pic" />
<button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in a working webpage that uploads the file but does not show the js alert.
I have also tried the following:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{
    $pic = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['pic']['name'];
    $pic_loc = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
    $folder="uploaded_files/";
    <script>var folder = "<?php echo $folder ?>";</script>
    <script>var pic = "<?php echo $pic ?>";</script>
    if(move_uploaded_file($pic_loc,$folder.$pic))
    {
        ?><script>alert('File successfully uploaded.\n![File Upload]('+window.location.href+folder+'/'+pic+')');</script><?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?><script>alert('Sorry, error while uploading file. Please try again');</script><?php
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Photo Uploader for use in markdown</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Photo Uploader & Markdown generator</h2>
<p>Click 'Choose file' to choose the file to be uploaded. The filename should appear. Then click 'upload'. <br>A popup should show you what to copy and paste.</p>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="pic" />
<button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in an http error 500

Any advice?

Many thanks,

Comment: What specifically did you try and how specifically did it not work?  What client-side code did it emit?  You appear to already be creating alerts, and the attempt you mention would be how to set the value of a variable in JavaScript.

Comment: The user experience would be better if you use AJAX instead

Comment: Just for clarification.. where your alert placed .. is it in between html block?

Comment: @David I tried the following in the alert section: `?><script>alert('File successfully uploaded.\n![File Upload]('+window.location.href+''. $folder .')');</script><?php` which resulted in no alert window. I also tried adding a line above the alert (also in the script) with the `var folder = "<?php echo $folder ?>";` and making the alert line as follows: `?><script>alert('File successfully uploaded.\n![File Upload]('+window.location.href+folder+')');</script><?php` which also resulted in no alert window

Comment: @CallumBreetzke: Code in comments isn't particularly readable.  Please include the exact code you're asking about *in the question*.

Comment: @user1844933 I placed my first code snippet at the top of my upload.php file. I then put in my html code: `<!DOCTYPE html>`
`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`
`<head>`
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` etc..

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, I will look at AJAX for next time

Comment: If I m correct js will work only between head tag and body tag

Comment: @David Thanks, I have updated my question

Comment: @user1844933 Thanks, I'll give that a try. My php file I uploaded above seemed to work (without trying to include the folder and file name) with the js at the top.

Comment: @CallumBreetzke: The copy/paste you did has the same problem as the comment above.  You have illegible code segments placed throughout a vague description of what the code looks like.  Stop describing what the code looks like and just *show the actual code*.  In the code you *are* showing there is *no* attempt to use the `$folder` variable in any of the JavaScript.  We want to help you, but until you can actually demonstrate the problem all we can do is make random guesses and potential suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in php and call it where ever you need to call alert.

Function :

```
function alertMsg($str) {
    print("<script>alert('$str')</script>");
}
```

And call in php as

```
//string
alertMsg("Success");

//php variable
$alertMsg = "Some alert message";
alertMsg($alertMsg);

//even you can concatenate both
alertMsg("This is an alert. ".$alertMsg);
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In both attempts you're trying to mix PHP, HTML, and JavaScript as though they were all the same language.  They are not.  From the perspective of any one of them, code in another one of them is nothing but a string.  They can't directly share variables and logic.

See how this line:

```
alert('File successfully uploaded.\n![File Upload]('+window.location.href+.$folder.'/'.$pic.')');
```

is attempting to use PHP code (both the variables *and* the syntax) directly in JavaScript.  This is simply resulting in syntax errors in your JavaScript, which your browser's development console is pointing out to you.  Instead, enclose the PHP code in `<?php ?>` tags and echo the result:

```
alert('File successfully uploaded.\n![File Upload]('+window.location.href+'<?php echo $folder.'/'.$pic ?>'+')');
```

The second attempt has the same problem, you're putting HTML/JavaScript directly in your PHP:

```
$folder="uploaded_files/";
<script>var folder = "<?php echo $folder ?>";</script>
```

This is resulting in PHP syntax errors, which your PHP logs are telling you about (as well as the 500 Internal Server Error you're getting).

PHP code needs to be in `<?php ?>` tags.  Always.  So this would be something like:

```
$folder="uploaded_files/";
?>
<script>var folder = "<?php echo $folder ?>";</script>
<script>var pic = "<?php echo $pic ?>";</script>
<?php
if(move_uploaded_file($pic_loc,$folder.$pic))
```

Note also that in HTML/JavaScript you don't need a `<script>` tag for *every line* of JavaScript code.  You can have multiple lines of code in a single `<script>` element.

Answer (score 0):

**Using variable PHP in JS**

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['btn-upload'])) {

    $pic     = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['pic']['name'];
    $pic_loc = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
    $folder  = "uploaded_files";

    if (move_uploaded_file($pic_loc, $folder . '/' . $pic)) { ?> 

      <script>
        alert("File successfully uploaded! " + 
              "\n" + 
              location.hostname + 
              "<?php echo '/' . $folder . '/' . $pic; ?>");
      </script>

<?php

    } else { ?>

      <script>alert("Sorry, error while uploading file. Please try again");</script>

<?php

    }

  }

?>
```

location.hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] `// localhost`